# Django - Deployment with Gunicorn, Nginx and Supervisor, Gunicorn error log

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn, supervisord

I've deployed a Django 1.6 app with Gunicorn + Nginx + Supervisor. Everything is working OK, but I have the Gunicorn error.log sending errors all the time. The file is huge, it sends errors to the log file every second.

The error from the Gunicorn error.log:

```
2014-02-27 14:25:09 [9235] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 18.0
2014-02-27 14:25:09 [9235] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('127.0.0.1', 8000)
2014-02-27 14:25:09 [9235] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
2014-02-27 14:25:10 [9235] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('127.0.0.1', 8000)
2014-02-27 14:25:10 [9235] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
2014-02-27 14:25:11 [9235] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('127.0.0.1', 8000)
2014-02-27 14:25:11 [9235] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
2014-02-27 14:25:12 [9235] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('127.0.0.1', 8000)
2014-02-27 14:25:12 [9235] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
2014-02-27 14:25:13 [9235] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('127.0.0.1', 8000)
2014-02-27 14:25:13 [9235] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
2014-02-27 14:25:14 [9235] [ERROR] Can't connect to ('127.0.0.1', 8000)
2014-02-27 14:25:16 [9250] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 18.0
    2014-02-27 14:25:16 [9250] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('127.0.0.1', 8000)
2014-02-27 14:25:16 [9250] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
2014-02-27 14:25:17 [9250] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('127.0.0.1', 8000)
2014-02-27 14:25:17 [9250] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
2014-02-27 14:25:18 [9250] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('127.0.0.1', 8000)
2014-02-27 14:25:18 [9250] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
2014-02-27 14:25:19 [9250] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('127.0.0.1', 8000)
2014-02-27 14:25:19 [9250] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
2014-02-27 14:25:20 [9250] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('127.0.0.1', 8000)
2014-02-27 14:25:20 [9250] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
2014-02-27 14:25:21 [9250] [ERROR] Can't connect to ('127.0.0.1', 8000)
2014-02-27 14:25:24 [9261] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 18.0
2014-02-27 14:25:24 [9261] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('127.0.0.1', 8000)
2014-02-27 14:25:24 [9261] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
2014-02-27 14:25:25 [9261] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('127.0.0.1', 8000)
2014-02-27 14:25:25 [9261] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
2014-02-27 14:25:26 [9261] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('127.0.0.1', 8000)
2014-02-27 14:25:26 [9261] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
2014-02-27 14:25:27 [9261] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('127.0.0.1', 8000)
2014-02-27 14:25:27 [9261] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
2014-02-27 14:25:28 [9261] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('127.0.0.1', 8000)
2014-02-27 14:25:28 [9261] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
2014-02-27 14:25:29 [9261] [ERROR] Can't connect to ('127.0.0.1', 8000)
```

My supervisor.conf:

```
[program:mydjangoapp]
command=/home/myuser/virtualenv_mydjangoapp/bin/python manage.py run_gunicorn
directory=/home/myuser/webapps/mydjangoapp
user=myuser
autostart=True
autorestart=True
stdout_logfile = /home/myuser/webapps/mydjangoapp_logs/gunicorn/out.log
stderr_logfile = /home/myuser/webapps/mydjangoapp_logs/gunicorn/err.log
```

My Nginx virtual.conf:

```
server {
   listen 80;
   client_max_body_size 1G;
   server_name 0.0.0.0;

   keepalive_timeout 5;
   access_log /home/myuser/webapps/mydjangoapp_logs/nginx/access.log;
   error_log /home/myuser/webapps/mydjangoapp_logs/nginx/error.log;

   location /static {
       alias /home/myuser/webapps/mydjangoapp_static;
   }

   location / {
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

       proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
       proxy_redirect off;
       proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
   }
}
```

My netstat -tulpn:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2719/python     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2606/mysqld     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:46028           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2757/beam.smp     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2613/nginx      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:4369            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2663/epmd       
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:85              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2613/nginx      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2469/sshd       
tcp6       0      0 :::5672                 :::*                    LISTEN      2757/beam.smp   
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      2469/sshd       
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           2395/dhclient3        
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:123             0.0.0.0:*                           3127/ntpd       
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1900            0.0.0.0:*                           2551/minissdpd        
udp6       0      0 ::1:123                 :::*                                3127/ntpd       
udp6       0      0 :::123                  :::*                                3127/ntpd
```

My supervisord.log:

```
2014-02-27 16:14:56,300 CRIT Supervisor running as root (no user in config file)
2014-02-27 16:14:56,303 CRIT Supervisor running as root (no user in config file)
2014-02-27 16:14:56,413 INFO RPC interface 'supervisor' initialized
2014-02-27 16:14:56,413 CRIT Server 'unix_http_server' running without any HTTP authentication checking
2014-02-27 16:14:56,414 INFO supervisord started with pid 2510
2014-02-27 16:14:56,651 INFO RPC interface 'supervisor' initialized
2014-02-27 16:14:56,651 CRIT Server 'unix_http_server' running without any HTTP authentication checking
2014-02-27 16:14:56,657 INFO daemonizing the supervisord process
2014-02-27 16:14:56,658 INFO supervisord started with pid 2687
2014-02-27 16:14:57,453 INFO spawned: 'celery' with pid 2786
2014-02-27 16:14:57,466 INFO spawned: 'mydjangoapp' with pid 2787
2014-02-27 16:14:57,666 INFO spawned: 'celery' with pid 2842
2014-02-27 16:14:57,673 INFO spawned: 'mydjangoapp' with pid 2846
2014-02-27 16:14:58,471 INFO success: mydjangoapp entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2014-02-27 16:14:58,676 INFO success: mydjangoapp entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2014-02-27 16:15:09,284 INFO success: celery entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 10 seconds (startsecs)
2014-02-27 16:15:09,313 INFO success: celery entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 10 seconds (startsecs)
2014-02-27 16:15:13,438 INFO exited: mydjangoapp (exit status 1; not expected)
2014-02-27 16:15:14,445 INFO spawned: 'mydjangoapp' with pid 3164
2014-02-27 16:15:15,830 INFO success: mydjangoapp entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2014-02-27 16:15:20,539 INFO exited: mydjangoapp (exit status 1; not expected)
2014-02-27 16:15:21,546 INFO spawned: 'mydjangoapp' with pid 3264
2014-02-27 16:15:22,549 INFO success: mydjangoapp entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2014-02-27 16:15:27,669 INFO exited: mydjangoapp (exit status 1; not expected)
2014-02-27 16:15:28,676 INFO spawned: 'mydjangoapp' with pid 3275
2014-02-27 16:15:29,679 INFO success: mydjangoapp entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2014-02-27 16:15:35,166 INFO exited: mydjangoapp (exit status 1; not expected)
2014-02-27 16:15:36,173 INFO spawned: 'mydjangoapp' with pid 3286
2014-02-27 16:15:37,175 INFO success: mydjangoapp entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2014-02-27 16:15:42,332 INFO exited: mydjangoapp (exit status 1; not expected)
2014-02-27 16:15:43,339 INFO spawned: 'mydjangoapp' with pid 3295
```

My supervisorctl status output:

```
root@li199-188:/var/log# supervisorctl status
celery                           RUNNING    pid 2842, uptime 0:04:05
mydjangoapp                      RUNNING    pid 3815, uptime 0:00:03
```

Any clue on what's causing the errors in the Gunicorn log file? As I said everything is working without a problem. The only problem is this log that keeps sending errors.

Best Regards,

Comment: `python manage.py run_gunicorn` run as a deamon?

Comment: @pbacterio, the command is the one in the supervisord.conf. There is a way of running "python manage.py run_gunicorn" as deamon?

Comment: looks like supervidor restarting the program wrongly. take a look at supervisor logs.

Comment: @pbacterio, I've update the initial post to include the supervisord.log. It looks that the problem is the supervisord but I can't figure out whats wrong. Any clue?

Comment: supervidor tells that your program is crashing. Your program need a virtualenvironment?

Comment: @pbacterio, Yes, it needs a virtualenv. I've added the "supervisorctl status" output to the initial post. It seems that supervisord keeps trying to launch new processes when there is no need.

Comment: Searh for the first error message, before `Connection in use:` errors.

Comment: @pbacterio, I've updated again the supervisord log and the "supervisorctl status". What is happening is that the PID of the "mydjangoapp" is always changing. The "celery" PID is stable.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48597/discussion-between-pbacterio-and-andre)

Answer (score 6):

This usually happens when gunicorn processes are retried a few times and if you happens to start a process on a port (8000 in your case) while the previous proc is about to finish and so on. So, you need to terminate all such processes individually.

- You can use `netstat -tulpn` to see the PID
- `kill -9 PID`

The other waiting procs will autostart in the cyclic wait case. so repeatedly check with `netstat` and kill them until no more processes are found running on that port.

Gunicorn processes should work fine at this point.

Answer (score 1):

As the error logs says, it looks like there's an application already listening on port 8000.
Maybe you launched gunicorn from command line ant it is already running in that port.

You could use *netstat -tulpn* to see if there's an instance of python listening on that port and kill it.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I've added my "netstat -tulpn" output. Python is running on PID 2719, the same PID of the supervisord process.